# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to.... ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, odac

I have a stored procedure with at least 30 parameters. Mostly specified with defaults, the ones not specified with defaults are deemed mandatory.

The following when executed through SQL plus works for me.

```
DECLARE
l_error_value NUMBER;
l_error_product VARCHAR2(10);
l_ce_doc_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
procedurename
( ce_cat => 'RO'
, ce_class => 'REP'
, ce_location => location value'
, ce_description => 'description value'
, ce_enquiry_type => 'IR'
, ce_source => 'W'
, ce_incident_datetime => '01-JAN-2014'
, ce_doc_outcome =>'FC'
, ce_doc_outcome_reason => 'First Contact'
, ce_doc_id => l_ce_doc_id
, error_value => l_error_value
, error_product => l_error_product
);
END;
/
```

Most are Varchar2, with the exception of date time (which is datetime), ce_doc_id which is number and error_product which is number.

When i try an use this with asp.net and oracle.dataaccess components, it consistently gives me:

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROCEDURE NAME'.

It is driving a bit insane now.

The following is my (albeit messy code).

```
 using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(oracleconnection.thisConnString()))
            {
                connection.Open();

                OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(procedureName, connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                OracleParameter thisParam = new OracleParameter();
                thisParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                thisParam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                thisParam.Value = "RO";
                thisParam.ParameterName = "ce_cat";
                OracleParameter thisParam2 = new OracleParameter();
                thisParam2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                thisParam2.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                thisParam2.Value = "REP";
                thisParam2.ParameterName = "ce_class";
                OracleParameter thisParam3 = new OracleParameter();
                thisParam3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                thisParam3.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                thisParam3.Value = "Location";
                thisParam3.ParameterName = "ce_location";
                OracleParameter thisParam4 = new OracleParameter();
                thisParam4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                thisParam4.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                thisParam4.Value = "Description";
                thisParam4.ParameterName = "ce_description";
                OracleParameter thisParam5 = new OracleParameter();
                thisParam5.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                thisParam5.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                thisParam5.Value = "IR";
                thisParam5.ParameterName = "ce_enquiry_type";
                OracleParameter thisParam6 = new OracleParameter();
                thisParam6.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                thisParam6.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                thisParam6.Value = "W";
                thisParam6.ParameterName = "ce_source";
                OracleParameter thisParam7 = new OracleParameter();
                thisParam7.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                thisParam7.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date;
                thisParam7.Value = DateTime.Now;
                thisParam7.ParameterName = "ce_incident_datetime";
                OracleParameter thisParam8 = new OracleParameter();
                thisParam8.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                thisParam8.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                thisParam8.Value = "FC";
                thisParam8.ParameterName = "ce_doc_outcome";
                OracleParameter thisParam9 = new OracleParameter();
                thisParam9.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                thisParam9.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                thisParam9.Value = "First Contact";
                thisParam9.ParameterName = "ce_doc_outcome_reason";

                OracleParameter thisParam10 = new OracleParameter();
                thisParam10.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                thisParam10.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal;
                thisParam10.ParameterName = "ce_doc_id";
                OracleParameter thisParam11 = new OracleParameter();
                thisParam11.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                thisParam11.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                thisParam11.ParameterName = "error_value";
                OracleParameter thisParam12 = new OracleParameter();
                thisParam12.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                thisParam12.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal;
                thisParam12.ParameterName = "error_product";

                command.Parameters.Add(thisParam);
                command.Parameters.Add(thisParam2);
                command.Parameters.Add(thisParam3);
                command.Parameters.Add(thisParam4);
                command.Parameters.Add(thisParam5);
                command.Parameters.Add(thisParam6);
                command.Parameters.Add(thisParam7);
                command.Parameters.Add(thisParam8);
                command.Parameters.Add(thisParam9);
                command.Parameters.Add(thisParam10);
                command.Parameters.Add(thisParam11);
                command.Parameters.Add(thisParam12);


                command.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
```

In the last version (as posted) I've replaced outputs with returnvalue to see if it made any difference - nothing.

Am i missing something or because i'm using asp.net and oracle odac do i need to specify all parameters, even those with default values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned tracing on through ODP.NET to see what it was generating in terms of SQL. It seems as though ODP.NET is funny about the date > OracleDbType.Date conversion and the value being fed into it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to debug these types of problems is to comment out all but one parameter in your C# code and your stored proc. Compile that and make sure it works. Then uncomment out 10 parameters, re-compile and see if that works. Keep doing this in chunks of 10 until the code breaks. Then you know it's one of the 10 you just added, so you can start adding those one by one until you find the one that breaks your code.

I call this technique "binary search debugging". :)

Also, if you are passing 30 parameters to an SP, you might want to see if you could simplify that procedure somehow. With that many parameters, things can become a bit unwieldy, as you've discovered.

Comment: The flexibility i would love, however the stored procedure is 3rd Party, and I have no flexibility to modify it in anyway. It is wierd how through SQLPlus it is fine.

Comment: @Jon Selby - Can you copy the stored procedure to a "sandbox" database where you could modify it there?

Comment: i could try, however my user account is quite restricted, i've not yet been able to view the source for the SP.

Comment: @Jon Selby - You might want to check with your DBA and see if they can get you the code.